# How to show Only if phone Number is present using contactpicker

Tags: java, android, contactpicker

I am using Contact picker library for selecting multiple contacts but if a contact doesn't contain any number and if it is selected then it is showing some null pointer exception in the edit text field. How to remove that message and also how to remove trailing comma. Below is my Code.

```
 try {
            int pos = 0;
            for (Contact contact : contacts) {
                String displayName = contact.getDisplayName();
                result.append(displayName + ",");
                result.setSpan(new BulletSpan(15), pos, pos + displayName.length() + 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                //pos += displayName.length() + 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            result.append(e.getMessage());
        }

        contactsView.setText(result);
```

Comment: which library you're using? does Contact class has any method to getPhoneNumber ?

Comment: com.onegravity.contactpicker this library........ContactPickerActivity is the class and yes it has a method to getPhoneNumber

Comment: then check if condition to check phone number is there or not, based on that update `result`

Answer (score 0):

please try to check this **code**

```
 void getAllContacts() {
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
    String[] list = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, list, selection, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String contactNumber =     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));


            contactNuber.add(contactNumber);
            contactsName.add(contactName);
            nameList.add(contactName);
            numberList.add(contactNumber);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        myContacts.put("name", nameList);
        myContacts.put("number", numberList);


    }

}
```